# Windows Update Error

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-update

Im trying to run windows updates after doing a clean install of windows xp pro but it gives me an error and says the windows update service is already running. I have tried restarting the service as well as rebooting the machine several times with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stupid question, but did you try waiting a while to see if it would finish running?

Comment: @Jikag no i havent.. let me try that

Comment: ok that did not work @jikag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured this out. I was trying to install sp3 via windows update but that didnt work so i tried to download the standalone version and install that and that failed also so i finally downloaded it on a different computer, put it on a disk and installed it manually that way and now it works perfectly! I still dont know why windows update didnt work in the first place because thats how microsoft recommends you install service packs but anyway its working now!

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen an error that says windows update service is *already* running. I usually see errors that says windows update service is **not** running. If the error is the service not running, try restarting the windows update service by running "services.msc" from run prompt, and use this tool to restart it. Also sometimes you need to go into windows update and disable it to "never check for update", and then re-enable it again to "check updates automatically".